# Django redirect with a custom error message

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-admin

I'm new in using django templating/frontend and I would like to redirect to a page with a custom message in django.

Here's what I've tried but I can't make It work.

**View**

```
return redirect("/login",custom_error="Try Again Later")
```

**Login.html**

```
{% if custom_error %}
<p class="errornote">
    {{ custom_error }}
</p>
{% endif %}
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: You should use the [*Django message framework*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/) for this. Please do *not* encode messages in the URL.

Answer (score 3):

Please do *not* encode error messages in the URL. You can use the [*Django message framework* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) for this.

Before you make the request, you add a message:

```
from django.contrib import messages

messages.error('Try again later')
return redirect('name-of-login-view')
```

It is furthermore better to specify the *name* of the view, instead of the path, since the path might later change.

In the template(s), probably best in a `base.html` template that is inherited by (most) other templates, you can then render this with:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Tried something like this but its displaying 2 error messages 1 from the messages.error and another from the code below.

{% if messages %}
  {% for message in messages %}
    <p class="errornote">
      {{ message }}
    <p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

Anyway I can disable the message from the messages.error I would want to display my message inside my own css

Comment: @shibs: I think it might be better to use the `message.tags` instead, since the message framework allows to send "info" messages, "success" messages, "warning" messages, etc. If you later want to send a message "order processed succesfully", you probably do not want to show that as an error?

Comment: @shibs: you can add extra loglevels, and for example use `'errornote'` on one of these: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#message-tags